# Why is java returning an error that constructor parameter is undefined?

Tags: java

```
public class A {
    String name;
    public A() {
       this("My Name");
    }
}
```

I came across this line of code from an ebook (Dietel_Java_HowTo) that I'm reading and also tried reading some article (javaworld/constructor) about constructor. They have used snippets of code like what I have on top. It's giving me an undefined String error.

Is the this keyword referring to the variable name, if so why am I getting the error. I'm new in java please bear.

Comment: Because the compiler is right. You don't have a constructor that takes a `String` parameter.

Comment: Also, you should have `String name;`, with a capital `S`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `this("My Name");` from inside a constructor, you are invoking another overloaded constructor of the Class `A`, but, you haven't define a constructor which accepts String argument. So compiler complains it.

Possible corrected version

```
public class A{
  String name;
  public A(){
    this("My Name");
  }
  public A(String name){
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no constructor of `A` that takes a `String`(also `string name` should be `String name`) as parameter. To correct it:

```
public class A{
  String name;
  public A(){
    this("My Name");
  }
  public A(String name){
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

Also, your program does not compile, `public class A(){}` is invalid.

Comment: Sorry for the typo error, I have corrected it already. But why have they defined it that way? We're they wrong?

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are trying to call the constructor with the `this("My Name")` call, but the constructor does not take any parameters. Try defining another constructor as shown below:

```
public class A() {
    string name;
    public A() {
       this("My Name");
    }
    public A(String a) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Have a look at [the java tutorial on constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) to get a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

In java by using this(parameters) keyword you can call the overloaded constructor. In your case you are facing compile time error due to you are trying to calling overloaded constructor which belongs to static polymorphism concept so its give compile time error. So you will have to need to add new constructor with single string parameter and your class would be change in to below class:

```
public class A{
  String name;
  public A(){
    this("My Name");
  }
  public A(String name){
    //your logic
  }
}
```